# Problem with filter function in React Router

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-router

So I have Free To Play Component which  is taking freetoplay data from json and displaying It. I have also a Link which should open up a Payment Route and pass the data from that Component that is pressed, In the Payment I have a filter function, Anyway when I press on the Link, it should render the image class and price, but it does not, I dont know why, its says "image not defined" Action is in another Component its taking the data from action object in json. Freetoplay is also anotherComponent it is taking the data from freetoplay Object in json.But anyway I would need to create "better filter function" in Payment in order to achieve the thing I want to – If anyone could help me I would be very grateful.I have asked this question 5 times already nobody gave me any hints/or Answers, Dont get consfused of filter in Free2Play component it is for search functionality

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import data from "../data.json";

function Payment() {  
    const { productId } = useParams();
    const filteredData = data.filter((product) => product.id === productId)[0];
    return (
        <div  className='Payment'>
         <img src={filteredData.image}></img>
         <h1>{filteredData.price}</h1>
         <h1>{filteredData.name}</h1>          
        </div>
    )
}

export default Payment

import React from 'react'
import data from "./data.json";
import {
    
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { SearchContext } from './SearchContext';


function FreeToPlay() {
  const {filterProduct}=React.useContext(SearchContext);
    return (
        <>
          <div className='All' >
            {data[0].freetoplay.filter(filterProduct).map((product) => {
              return (
                <div className='f2p' key={product.id}>               
                    <img src={product.image}></img>
                    <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                    <h5>{product.price}</h5>
                  <Link
            to={`/payment/${product.id}`}
            className='link'
           >
            Buy Now
           </Link>
        </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      );
}

export default FreeToPlay

json
[
  {
    "freetoplay": [{
        "id": "0",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "60$",
        "name": "CS Go"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "6$",
        "name": "Fifa"
      }
    ],
 
    "action": [{
        "id": "2",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "60$",
        "name": "doom"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "66$",
        "name": "cyberpunk"
      }
    ],
    
  }
]


this is the Route

 <Route exact path="/payment/:productId">
            <Payment/>
 </Route> 

Context but it is not so important

import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

export const SearchContext =React.createContext(null)
export  default function SearchProvider({children}) {

const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState("");


function filterProduct(product) {
     return product.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
     }
      return( 

       <SearchContext.Provider value ={{filterProduct,   searchValue, setSearchValue}}>
             {children} 
        </SearchContext.Provider> 
             
             ); }
```